# XMLGregorian Calender get a date from sql

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to convert simple date into XML GregorianCalender date.where date is saved in sql table and I am accessing date from there.my code is working fine but I am getting current date and time instead I want to get the specific date which user has enterd e.g 2019-12-24T08:00:06.000+01:00 but I am getting 2020-02-17T08:00:06.000+01:00...here is my code

```
else if (data.getClass().getName().equals("java.sql.Date"))
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(new Date());
XMLGregorianCalendar xCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
method.invoke(obj, xCal);
else
        ....
```

how to fix this problem. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Simple thing... Don't set *now* (`new Date()`) in `setTime()` but set the value from `data`. Maybe just `cal.setTime(data);` instead? By the way, have a look at the modern way to handle dates, times and anything related: [`java.time`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

Comment: I tried it but it is giving following error "The method setTime(Date) in the type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (Object)"

Comment: then you need to parse that parameter to Date, and then set it in cal.setTime(...)